# Am I missing something fundamental about the State Monad? Why keep state and input separately?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

Why our functions need to take a state and an input and not just a state that includes the input (or an input that includes the state?).

I assume that you might want to apply different inputs with the same state and therefore you want to keep them separately, but is that the only reason?

I *feel* that I'm missing something fundamental, but I can't grasp it.

Comment: Our functions are normally curried. That's just the way we work. Why should these functions be any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the conveniency. In general, separate arguments, if they are *conceptually* separated (I mean, they aren't properties of a single object, for example), are better than packed in a datatype, because in the former case you can use currying, combinators and other advantages of functional approach.

Without monads, each stateful function would look like `foo :: b -> s -> (s, a)`, and with monads, we can extract the common part, name it: `newtype State s a = State (s -> (s, a))`, and define `return` and `>>=` for it. Moreover, any simple function `bar :: a -> b` can be easily turned into a stateful via a simple change of the result: `bar :: a -> State s b`. That would be impossible if both input and state were carried in a single argument (say, a tuple: `foo :: (s, a) -> (s, a)`.

Comment: You begin with "That's due to the conveniency", but you end with "That would be impossible", so, is it a conveniency or a necessity? (Very insightful your definition of conceptually separated and the possible advantages of separating arguments)

Comment: By "impossible" I mean a particular case of transforming a stateless function into a stateful by only changing the result type. Overall, it would be harder to live with a PackedState monad :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your actual question is but here are some facts that could probably answer it:

1. State data is mutable (via the `State` monad), input data is immutable. In Haskell it's conventional to achieve maximum of type-level safety. If you unite input with state you'll make it mutable too for no purpose.
2. Monads do not have inputs. You might be thinking about [arrows](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows). And in fact there is [a state arrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.1.2/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer-State.html).

Comment: hmmm, 1. would explain why the monadic function has the type:a -> s -> (s, b)   (the state's type remains constant, the input type might change)

Comment: @LayGonzález It would be more correct to speak about just `s -> (s, b)`, since that is what actually [makes the `State` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#StateT). The `a ->` part has nothing to do with the `State` monad, since as mentioned in "2." monads have nothing to do with inputs, unlike arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The State monad is useful because it enforces a pattern which is obvious from the type.

Instead of having every function in your code look like:

```
foo state x y = ... return (state', z)
```

you can use `State` to make clear what your intent is.

Comment: true but off topic, isn't it?

Comment: My point is that there is nothing fundamental that you're missing. State is just a programming abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Terminology:  if you are new to Haskell it is easy to get confused/fooled by statements like "State data is mutable".  Someone coming from imperative programs might take "mutable" to mean change the value in an existing location.  For some parts of Haskell (e.g., `IORef`) that is indeed true.  In the `State` monad case it is not true.

`State` supports mutating a state into a NEW state - the new state is completely independent of the old state.  Nothing is mutated in place.

Sometimes this is called "effectful" programming - you get the benefits of effects but without using  "real" side-effects - `State` is completely pure.